# Disable horizontal scroll where element is larger than viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

I've trying to create something a bit like the navigation on google play, with a fixed number og tabs (the swyping in app-browsing).

I've created a div that contains some content divs.

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="section"> ... </div>
    <div class="section"> ... </div>
    <div class="section"> ... </div>
</div>
```

To create the sliding between sections I set the container to a width of 300 %
I then set the left property of the container according to the button pressed.

My question is: How to disable horizontal scrolling of viewport?

Answer (score 2):

You have two solutions:

1. Wrap `#container` inside another `<div>` which has 100% width, disabled wrap and overflow: hidden, then scroll `#container` inside it, or
2. Put `overflow: hidden` on the viewport (or try with `overflow-x:hidden);`

Comment: Your first solutions fixed my problem. Thanks alot !